# Mongo service crashed. Need to find reason of crash

Tags: mongodb

Today morning I found the following error with mongo, on my server.

```
*** System restart required ***
You have mail.
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
Wed Nov 25 05:18:51.381 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

It crashed my website. How can I find what stopped mongo service? Do mongo have logs for this? Where can I find them? Also How to make sure if if mongodb is crashed then it restart service as well?

I restarted mongodb service and website started working again.

Output of ps -ef | grep mongod:

```
mongodb   14756      1  0 05:20 ?        00:00:14 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
ubuntu    36865  14123  0 06:18 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongod
```

Comment: what is the output of ps -ef | grep mongod?

Comment: Calm down. First of all, the system does not tell you for fun that it needs to be restarted. Have you updated the system and/or MongoDB? What happens when you start MongoDB? Have you tried to restart your server? What happens then?

Comment: I didn't update mongodb since long, and when i started mongodb service, everything started working again.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue. After some searching I guessed it was os that sacrificed `mongod` for memory. If kernel killed your mongod you can find the logs in kernel logs

Mostly kernel logs will be in `/var/log/kern.log`, The logs might be rotated.

So better to do a grep

`grep mongod /var/log/kern.log*`

if the logs are archived
`find -name \*kern.log.*.gz -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep "mongod"`

```
./kern.log.1:Nov 12 12:55:04 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [8413229.118361] mongod invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24201ca, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
./kern.log.1:Nov 12 12:55:04 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [8413229.118365] mongod cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
./kern.log.1:Nov 12 12:55:04 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [8413229.118371] CPU: 0 PID: 1830 Comm: mongod Not tainted 4.4.0-1062-aws #71-Ubuntu
./kern.log.1:Nov 12 12:55:04 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [8413229.118531] [ 1301]   112  1301   300787   181207     485       4        0             0 mongod
./kern.log.1:Nov 12 12:55:04 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [8413229.118680] Out of memory: Kill process 1301 (mongod) score 355 or sacrifice child
./kern.log.1:Nov 12 12:55:04 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [8413229.130161] Killed process 1301 (mongod) total-vm:1203148kB, anon-rss:724828kB, file-rss:0kB
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this post is very old now. I have already found my answers from sources outside of StackOverflow.

Comment: This doesn't tell anything. You will have to turn on the `MongoDB` logs and also see the entries in `Syslog`, that helps sometimes. Your suggestion doesn't provide any help for automating the restart process of MongoDB.

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper In SO you can answer own question!

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper , Can you please share how you have solve your problem? OR have you got anything to restart mongo service automatically?

Answer (score 3):

According to MongoDB documentation

> The getLog command returns a document with a log array that contains
>   recent messages from the mongod process log.

Please try executing following command in mongo shell to return logs which consist of information related to errors or warnings while initialization of  mongod service

```
db.adminCommand({getLog: "startupWarnings" })
```

For detailed description regarding **getLog** method please refer the documentation mentioned in following URL

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLog/

Comment: Nothing happened, it returned me { "totalLinesWritten" : 0, "log" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }
.I think i will start recording for  errors now. but won't show any previous entries

Comment: This command show logs for the current instance of mongod, not the previous instances, so past errors won't be here. As stated in the URL you pointed: `getLog does not read log data from the mongod log file.`

Answer (score 1):

My server also crashed for no obvious reason. The other answers did not throw anything. But I found the following looking at the `mongod.conf` file in `/etc/`.

There are also logs inside `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`. It seems that by default it has a 500 Mb limit. But is still a big file.

There I found that my server crashed at a certain time, but couldn't find the reason.

```
2019-04-17T19:39:11.700+0000 I COMMAND  [conn460] command cge_info_system.expedientes command: find { find: "expedientes", filter: { NoExpediente: "090311-497449" }, limit: 1, $db: "cge_info_system", $readPreference: { mode: "primaryPreferred" }, lsid: { id: UUID("f18d952b-37e7-4a45-bf31-b89a596057d1") } } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:49360 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:386 nreturned:1 reslen:3224 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 387 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 387 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 387 } } } protocol:op_msg 1416ms
2019-04-23T16:35:19.578+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2019-04-23T16:35:19.599+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-04-23T16:35:19.958+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=741 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=bb7dd22f-cb77-4c6b-9c4c-9fddcfc2cc00.clouding.host
2019-04-23T16:35:19.958+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.5
2019-04-23T16:35:19.958+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3739429dd92b92d1b0ab120911a23d50bf03c412
2019-04-23T16:35:19.958+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
2019-04-23T16:35:19.958+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-04-23T16:35:19.958+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-04-23T16:35:19.958+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-04-23T16:35:19.958+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2019-04-23T16:35:19.958+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-04-23T16:35:19.958+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-04-23T16:35:19.958+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2019-04-23T16:35:19.961+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock is not empty.
2019-04-23T16:35:19.962+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2019-04-23T16:35:19.962+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2019-04-23T16:35:19.962+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
```

In there is also a reference to a directory called `/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data` but the data in there are binary files. I haven't got much info from there.