# How to prevent mongod from crashing due to a query when it has a lot of documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When I try to make simple query like `db.getCollection('logs').find({ exampleField: { $exists: true } }).count()` mongodb instance crashes.

Result of `db.runCommand({ dbStats: 1, scale: 1024*1024 })`:

```
{
    "db" : "mydb",
    "collections" : 7,
    "views" : 0,
    "objects" : 709903,
    "avgObjSize" : 593.484264751663,
    "dataSize" : 401.798496246338,
    "storageSize" : 177.4921875,
    "numExtents" : 0,
    "indexes" : 7,
    "indexSize" : 11.35546875,
    "fsUsedSize" : 27454.1953125,
    "fsTotalSize" : 50283.80859375,
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Please note that this is with using a scale of 1024*1024(so data is in MB).

I would like to know can something be done to the database so that we can run queries just like we used to do before?

EDIT: Here are the mongodb installation details

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.3
git version: xxxx
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: debian81
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Comment: Seems to be this is about mongoDB optimization removed 2 tags so this looks clean, So from my exp. I can say your DB is not a huge one, it should withstand with simple queries like this, So from the given data, I can say you don't have much data in your DB - additionally when it says `"indexes" : 7`, So no indexes have been created !! Please create appropriate indexes on all collections(Mainly on logs collection). As you only have `700K` docs overall DB shouldn't be said a huge one though, Also you can try `db.getCollection('logs').count({ exampleField: { $exists: true } })`

Comment: What is the error message you get when _"... mongodb instance crashes."_?

Comment: @prasad_ there are no error messages. For example this is the last few lines https://pastebin.com/7MJfbvwb . Most of the lines are really similar, contain no errors. The next message it jus says `***** SERVER RESTARTED *****`. That is it

Comment: @srinivasy indexes will definitely make things faster, I'll create indexes, but simple queries like this one shouldn't restart the mongod process right?

Comment: could there be a problem due to RAM, we just have 1GiB of RAM.

Comment: @hungrywolf : Did you check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909393/mongo-service-crashed-need-to-find-reason-of-crash

Comment: My mongod keeps crashing because `Out Of Memory killer` keeps killing it, my vps has really low RAM for that query.

Comment: @srinivasy thanks for the link